# Apply a for loop (or apply substitute) across a list of uneven element lengths

Tags: r, indexing, apply, xts, lapply

I am looking to extract a range of values from a list of xts objects, based on index positions in another list. Now that you have the general idea, allow me to be more specific.

I have two lists:

1. the first contains several xts objects with data
2. the second contains vectors of numeric index values for which i want to extract data from the first list. if it helps, these index values represent maxima/minima of a time series. therefore, the lengths of each vector are not uniform as each time series has varying amounts of maxima/minima.

Now, given that I know the length of the numeric vector of index values, I can construct a for loop to extract a range of values like this:

```
# simple example ----------------------------------------------------------
s <- Sys.Date()-11
e <- Sys.Date()

# xts list
obj.xts <- xts(seq(.01,.12,by=.01),seq(from=s, to=e, by=1))
evens <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
odds <- evens-1

mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(evens)){
   mylist[[i]] <- obj.xts[odds[i]:evens[i]]  
}
```

However, my current problem looks more like this:

```
# still need a solution ---------------------------------------------------
even.list <- list(evens,evens[4])
odd.list <- list(odds,odds[4])

obj.xts2 <- xts(cbind(obj.xts,rev(obj.xts)),index(obj.xts))
split.xts <- list(obj.xts2[,1],obj.xts2[,2])

# desired output, first list element
out1 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][1]:even.list[[1]][1]]
out2 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][2]:even.list[[1]][2]]
out3 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][3]:even.list[[1]][3]]
out4 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][4]:even.list[[1]][4]]
out5 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][5]:even.list[[1]][5]]
out6 <- split.xts[[1]][odd.list[[1]][6]:even.list[[1]][6]]

# from list element 2
out7 <- split.xts[[2]][odd.list[[2]][1]:even.list[[2]][1]]


# FINAL OUTPUT
desiredOutput <- list(out1,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6,out7)
```

Here is what I have tried, but I keep getting stuck on the fact that the lengths of maxima/minima index values vary in length:

1. A double for loop

   ```
   mylist2 <- list()
   for(i in 1:??){
     for(j in 1:length(split.xts)){
       mylist2[[i]] <- split.xts[[j]][odd.list[[j]][i]:even.list[[j]][i]]
     }
   }
   ```
2. I've tried creating a new list of strings containing the entire range of values, so that I only have to loop through these names... something like:

   ```
    split.xts[[1]][paste(odd.list[[1]][6],even.list[[1]][6],sep=":")]
   ```
3. lapply, but honestly nothing i'm proud of.

   ```
   lapply(split.xts, function(x) x[odd.list:even.list])
   ```

Is there another function in the apply family that can help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I have a headeack trying to understand what you try to do!  I am pretty sure you are looking for something like `mapply(function(l,i)l[i],ts_list,index_list)`

Comment: haha sorry agstudy! you are definitely on the right track and gave me a great tip with mapply. i guess it's unclear, but if it helps, the "odds" are the start of the range that i want to collect and the "evens" are the stops. i think i just need modify your mapply function to extract the range of data. thank you!

Comment: i edited your function, but am getting the warnings "numerical expression has 1009 elements: only the first used" so, the output you provided me is accurate, but only first element. i'm going to try rapply to see if i can go through each vector element

Comment: Your 'evens' and 'odds' are hardly worth creating. Why not just specify `some_data[j:j+1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mapply` or `Map` is the way to go when you want to vectorize a function using arguments in a symmetric way.

So Something like this :

```
## function subset an xts object giving a min/max lists
min_max_subset <- function(l,min_list,max_list)
  Map(function(x,y)l[seq(x,y)],min_list,max_list)
## Vectorized version of the previous function 
Map(min_max_subset ,split.xts,odd.list,  even.list)
```